# How do you scrape javascript using selenium & BS3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble with scraping javascript.
I want to scrape some numbers from [this ESPN](http://www.espn.co.uk/rugby/matchstats?gameId=291168&league=244293) webpage but I had the look at the HTML and have no idea how. It seems like I've tried everything that I know but I can't. So how, for example, do I scrape the 435 or 677 located under meters run?
This is the current code I have :

```
url = "http://www.espn.co.uk/rugby/matchstats?gameId=291168&league=244293"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
teams_spans = soup.find_all("span", { "class" : "long-name" })
home_team = teams_spans[0].text
away_team = teams_spans[1].text
```

Want to scrape the data but have no clue how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Selenium for parsing the elements instead of using BeautifulSoup.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.espn.co.uk/rugby/matchstats?gameId=291168&league=244293')

spans = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('chartValue')
for span in spans[0:2]:
    print(span.text)
```

Output:

```
435
677
```